# Как нарисовать символами крест?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Начал изучать Python, попалось задание нарисовать через цикл в консоле крест.
Как это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте сначала что-то сделать сами и если что-то не будет получаться, покажите место в коде, с которым вам надо помочь.

Comment: @Axenow спасибо, следующий раз так и буду делать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in range(12):
    if 3 < i < 8:
        print('*'*12)
    else:
        print(' '*4+'*'*4)
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то в диапазон надо задать макс кол. звезд? 
только не понял для чего надо if?

Comment: @Hotosho Тут всё очень просто.Диапазон задает количество строк для печати (0-11 - то есть, всего 12 строк). Цикл печатает построчно. 12 звезд - это четыре строки перекладины креста - с 3 по 7 включительно - if проверяет порядковый номер строки, и если он попадает в диапазон с 3 по 7 включительно, печатает 12 звезд, иначе - 4 пробела и 4 звезды.

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in range(4):
    print("    ****")
for line in range(4):
    print("************")
for line in range(4):
    print("    ****")
```

Comment: Но ведь в задании написано через цикл :)

Comment: @Alexshev92 Ай, блин, точно. Прочитал же и забыл тут же :)